# jQuery: changing div css from display:none to display:block not working

Tags: jquery, css

I am changing the content of a div based on the checkbox value. the value of the div is simple text for all but one checkbox option. In the exception case, the value of div is another div (lets say childDiv).

So I am changing the the visibility of the childDiv (`display: none` through `jQuery.css()`) when the other two options are clicked, and changing it to `display: block` when the exception option is clicked.

The childDiv becomes hidden when I change checkbox option. However it does not display back again when I want it to be visible.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/jLgyp/

The code is

```
            <div class="switch switch-three candy blue" id="reachout">
                <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-41" value="1" checked="checked"/>
                    <label for="tab-41">Experience</label>
                <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-42" value="2"/>
                    <label for="tab-42">Contact Us</label>
                <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-43" value="3"/>
                    <label for="tab-43">Why?</label>
                <div id="test1234">
                    <div id="test12345">
                        Option Start
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="slide-button"></span>
            </div>
```

and

```
     jQuery("input[name='reachout']",jQuery('#reachout')).change(
        function(e)
        {                   
            if(jQuery(this).val()=="1") 
            {
                jQuery("#test1234").html("");
                jQuery("#test12345").css("display","block");
            }
            if(jQuery(this).val()=="2") 
            {
                jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");
                jQuery("#test12345").css("display","none");
            }
            if(jQuery(this).val()=="3") 
            {
                jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 3");
                jQuery("#test12345").css("display","none");
            }
        });
```

I even tried

```
            jQuery("#test12345").css('position', 'absolute');
            jQuery("#test12345").css('z-index', 3000);
```

after `display: block` but that didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: can you try to show() also the div? Perhaps this will work, since original div is hidden with display:no. Something like: jQuery("#test12345").css("display","block").show();

Comment: @andrew Tried it . Still doesnt work.

Comment: On a side note, to make your code more concise, you can try using case/switch instead of multiple if statements ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the div when you set is parent 's html, so you're trying to show a div thats not there.

Answer (score 2):

See what is your problem:

This `jQuery("#test1234")` is the parent of `jQuery("#test12345")` and what you are doing is overwritten the html of it with these lines of code:

```
jQuery("#test1234").html("");
jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");
jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 3");
```

See before this script's execution the `HTML` was like this:

```
           <div id="test1234">
                <div id="test12345">
                    Option Start
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now when your scripts gets executed then it looks like this:

by this `jQuery("#test1234").html("");` output is like:

```
           <div id="test1234">

            </div>
```

by this `jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");` output is like:

```
           <div id="test1234">
                Option 2
            </div>
```

and by this `jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");` output is like:

```
           <div id="test1234">
                Option 3
            </div>
```

**So you are doing `display : block` an element which is not present in the dom after script execution.**

Answer (score 0):

Just one change in jquery!!

```
jQuery("input[name='reachout']",jQuery('#reachout')).change(
                function(e)
                {                   
                    if(jQuery(this).val()=="1") 
                    {
            --> change in this line         jQuery("#test1234").html("Option Start");
                        jQuery("#test12345").css('position', 'absolute');
                        jQuery("#test12345").css("display","block");
                        jQuery("#test12345").css('z-index', 3000);
                    }
                    if(jQuery(this).val()=="2") 
                    {
                        jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");
                        jQuery("#test12345").hide();
                    }
                    if(jQuery(this).val()=="3") 
                    {
                        jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 3");
                        jQuery("#test12345").hide();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrew's comment, I decided to put the divs seperate instead of parent-child.

Thereafter it works fine as I desire.

The change in code is:

```
<div class="switch switch-three candy blue" id="reachout">
                        <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-41" value="1" checked="checked"/>
                            <label for="tab-41">Experience</label>
                        <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-42" value="2"/>
                            <label for="tab-42">Contact Us</label>
                        <input name="reachout" type="radio" id="tab-43" value="3"/>
                            <label for="tab-43">Why?</label>
                        <div id="test1234">
                        </div>
                            <div id="test12345">
                                Option Start
                            </div>
                        <span class="slide-button"></span>
                    </div>
```

and

```
         jQuery("input[name='reachout']",jQuery('#reachout')).change(
            function(e)
            {                   
                if(jQuery(this).val()=="1") 
                {
                    jQuery("#test1234").hide();
                    jQuery("#test12345").show();
                }
                if(jQuery(this).val()=="2") 
                {
                    jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 2");
                    jQuery("#test1234").show();
                    jQuery("#test12345").hide();
                }
                if(jQuery(this).val()=="3") 
                {
                    jQuery("#test1234").html("Option 3");
                    jQuery("#test1234").show();
                    jQuery("#test12345").hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Id correct ?

```
jQuery("#test1234").html("");
jQuery("#test12345").css("display","block")
```

Comment: yup ...I have pasted html too

Answer (score 0):

Just use like below

```
// xxx is your div id
$('#xxx').hide();
$('#xxx').show();
```

It'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have reconfigured your code with some suggestions it should work now.

http://jsfiddle.net/jquery4u/nPMvV/

```
(function ($) {

    $("input[name='reachout']").on('change', function (e) {
        var checkVal = $(this).val();
        console.log(checkVal);

        //cache elements which are used often
        var $test1234 = $("#test1234"),
            $test12345 = $("#test12345");

        //use a switch statement instead of long winded if else
        switch (checkVal) {
            case "1":
                $test1234.html("Option 1");
                $test12345.show();
                break;
            case "2":
                $test1234.html("Option 2");
                $test12345.hide();
                break;
            case "3":
                $test1234.html("Option 2");
                $test12345.hide();
                break;

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```